# Tapping URL doesn't work in TTTAttributedLabel while there is a UITapGestureRecognizer on its superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, tttattributedlabel

There is container view and a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it. And it also has a subview which kind of `TTTAttributedLabel`.

When I remove the gesture recognizer from the container view, the delegate method of `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate`

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url can be called.
```

When I add the gesture recognizer on container view. Only its action method gets called. The delegate method of `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` won't be called.

Now I need the delegate method to be called when I tap on a link in `TTTAttributedLabel`, and action method to called when I tap on other area of container view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use this `gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch` for detection your event.

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
      if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[TTTAttributedLabel class]])
      {
           return FALSE;
      }
      else
      {

         return TRUE;
      }
}
```

you can also use  `if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]])` for all UIControl e.g Button even detect with `UIGestureRecognizer`. hope this help's you

Answer (score 8):

I tried @Nitin's solution but it has a problem as @n00bProgrammer pointed out. Furthermore, user experience became very bad. I had to tap several times to fire tapGesture which is added on a superView.

Here you have a better solution. TTTAttributedLabel has a useful instance method like below.

```
- (BOOL)containslinkAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

This returns whether an NSTextCheckingResult is found at the given point.

So, use the following code snippet then only link added part of the text will be working as a tappable link and the rest of area will fire your tapGesture as you desired. User experience is excellent as well.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([yourTTTAttributedLabel containslinkAtPoint:[touch locationInView:yourTTTAttributedLabel]])
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of the gesture recognizer to NO.

```
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Comment: Found your answer very late. Unfortunately spent 5 hours before found it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

@Nitin's answer is somewhat correct provided you do not want the tap gesture to work if user taps on part of your label, which is not a link. In case your label has text other than just the link, I suggest you do the following :

- Create a new delegate method (like "handleSingleTap") in the `TTTAttributedLabel.h` file as `@optional`.
- In `TTTAttributedLabel.m` find the `touchesEnded` method. Here you have an `if (self.activeLink)` condition.
- Create an `else` case for this condition as follows :

  ```
  else {

      if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleSingleTap)]) {

          [self.delegate handleSingleTap];            
      }
  }
  ```
- Override this new delegate method in your class where you use the label.

This way, if the user taps a link, the `if` takes care of handling link selection. If user taps text other than link, the `else` will call the method in your class (which is the target method for your `tapGesture`).

Also, remove the `tapGesture` from your view, or use @Nitin's code to NOT handle taps on your label, and let the label handle the tap on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Nitin's suggestion didn't work for me (uncertain why), but **this did**:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        if touch.view !== self.myTTTAttributedLabel {
            // Handle container view tap
        }
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

You must also **remove the gesture recognizer from your container view** and handle those taps in the if-clause above instead.

Answer (score 0):

> here is my solution

```
override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view == self.lblContent {
        gr?.isEnabled = false
        return false
    }
    else {
        gr?.isEnabled = true
        return true
    }
}
```

**gr** is my view's gesture and **lblContent(TTTAttributedLabel)** is my label  when i click label both gesture was working same time (label's gesture and view's gesture) so I have solved this problem with above code

> what i have tried before solution

```
cancelsTouchesInView = false
isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```